# Objective-c modern runtime using both properties and ivars in interface block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, instance-variables, modern-runtime

I've seen code examples (from the book Beginning iPhone 4 Development) where they both declare ivars inside the interface block and then declare properties for the same. Like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UITableView *table;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
```

What would be the purpose/benefit of this? As I understand that with the modern runtime version (iPhone and 64-bit OS X applications) you only need to declare properties and can leave out declaring the ivars inside the interface block. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903651/is-there-any-reason-to-declare-ivars-if-youre-using-properties-exclusively-in-ob/4909296#4909296) answer in a similair thread it would be for debugging purposes. But are there any other benefits except for debugging that you would use this approach?

Cheers,

Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicitly declaring ivars gives you the possibility to internally use a specialized type for the ivar.

A typical example is an internally mutable object that can be accessed from outside in a readonly, immutable way.

Example:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSArray *bars;
@end

@implementation
{
    NSMutableArray *bars;
}

@synthesize bars;

- (void)addBar:(Bar *)bar
{
    [bars addObject:bar];
}
@end
```

Of course the object returned from the `bars` property is not really immutable. But the point is that the API does not reveal its mutability.

Note that I used the fancy new private-ivars-in-implementation style. It's depending on the modern runtime as well as the clang compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Some programmers like to define their iVars with a slightly different name to differentiate between direct access and KVC access. For example:

in the .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UITableView *_table;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
```

and in the .m

```
@synthesize table = _table;
```

this way you directly access the iVar using `_table` but you use the synthesized setters and getters using `[self table]`

Comment: There's no need to declare the ivar explicitly to give it another name than the property. `@synthesize foo = _foo;` declares the name implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

> But are there any other benefits except for debugging that you would use this approach?

i declare the ivars explicitly for:

- access control (visibility)
- organization
- uniform written style
- compatibility (hey, this program could support 32 bit one day)
- and because i associate properties as a part of the class's public interface (although exceptions to this exist) - not simply as accessors to the class's ivars.

"everything as a read/write property" is fundamentally flawed ood.