# somebody please explain this?

Tags: objective-c, methods, user-defined-functions

These methods are inside a class called Rectangle, this is a part of the implementation file Rectangle.m

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

- (void)setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt {
    origin = pt;
}

- (XYPoint *)origin {
    return origin;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Not much special to Objective-C about it. It's just the setter and getter for a property called `origin`.

When you set a new origin using either

```
self.origin = /*some new value*/;
```

or

```
[self setOrigin: /*some new value*/];
```

the first method is going to be called.

In the same way the other method is called when you get value using either `self.origin` or `[self origin]` (but for the second method)

---

### Naming convention

You usually call these methods "setters and getters" or simply "accessors". In other languages, like Java, it is common to name these methods `setXyz` and `getXyz` but Objective-C names them `setXyz` and `xyz` for the getter.

### Properties vs. Instance variables

These days you seldom have to write these methods yourself. You get the same benefits by using a `property` and letting the compiler generate this boilerplate code for you. The property in your example would look something like this and replace all that code:

```
@property (weak) XYPoint *origin; // weak since your methods are not retaining the new value
```

You can read about the reason to use properties vs instance variables [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478038/reason-to-use-ivars-vs-properties-in-objective-c/11478172#11478172). In short: having a method wrap the variable enables you to have memory management (like copying or retaining) of objects and makes it possible to call other methods enabling KVC/KVO but it has a slight overhead to it.

Comment: I understand that they are a setter and a getter but why are they not in this format?

    -(void) setOrigin: (int) n
    { 
      origin = n;
    }
    -(int) origin
    {
      return origin;
    }

Comment: Do you mean `int` instead of `XYPoint *`?

Comment: yes, I mean why is it in the -(XYPoint *) and not in the -(int) format?
we could simply use -(void) setOrigin : (int) n as a setter and -(int) origin  as a getter.

Comment: An integer is only one number so it would only be able to represent either the x _or_ y coordinate of the point (or z if you are in 3D). The point is an object which I assume has an x and a y property in turn. So the rectangle class probably have both a point (x, y) and a size (width, height).

Comment: You have imported XYPoint in your header. I think this is an example teaching you to add a XYPoint class as an instance in your Rectangle Class. And it's demonstrating how the getter and setter for XYPoint instance.