# @syntesize not working in xcode4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to ios development and xcode.

Now i was taught that in xcode4.6 programmer doesn't need to use `@synthesize` statement as the IDE automatically does it for you.

However i don't know why my ide is not setting it then.

`@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *dictionary;`

and when i try to set something to it

`dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:resource];`

it says undeclared identifier did you mean _dictionary. No i did not mean _dictionary i meant dictionary. So when i manually add synthesize property in implementation everything seems to be working fine.

Can somebody tell me what's going on in here.

Comment: None of this has to do with Xcode. Auto-synthesis is a function of the Objective-C compiler, not the IDE you happen to be using.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying instance variable for that property is in fact `_dictionary`. That is how auto synthesised properties work.

However you should consider using the accessors to set the property (using `self.dictionary =` instead). See [this answer to "Reason to use ivars vs properties in objective c"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478172/608157) for reasons behind this.

---

Also, consider changing the `strong` property to `copy` for classes like NSDictionary, NSArray and NSString to prevent mistakes where a mutable subclass (NSMutableString, NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary) is assigned to the property and then mutated.

Comment: Pardon me if i am wrong here but if i have to directly access instance variable what's the purpose of a property then in the first place ?

Comment: @WinCoder Exactly ;) You probably just forgot to write `self.` before the name of the property. Not writing "self." has always accessed the variable directly.

Comment: @WinCoder You very rarely need to access the instance variable directly.

Answer (score 2):

`@synthesize dictionary` would have previously been written as `@synthesize dictionary = _dictionary` where `_dictionary` would be the variable related with the getters and setters generated by @synthesize.

It is safe to skip the `= _variableName` since XCode 4, but it will generate a variable matching the name of the synthesised attribute.

`dictionary` in your case, is only to be used as a setter and a getter, as `[self setDictionary:object]` or `[self dictionary]`.

If you want to manually assign it a value, then you use `_dictionary = object`;
Be sure to understand that doing so is not KVC compliant. You will need to inform any observers that the value is about to change.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `self.`:

```
self.dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:resource];
```

`self.dictionary` calls the setter method of the dictionary object, where as `dictionary` alone attempts to address a variable, either local to the function or an instance variable of the object.  In your case you want to address the setter method.

Comment: Yes, but in that case it's `[self setDictionary:...];`.

Comment: ahhh it so much better in C#.

Answer (score -3):

> `_dictionary` is equivalent to `self.dictionary` in Xcode4.6

This is to make sure that you are accessing the objects of the same current class.

Comment: Naaah, not exactly. There *is* a difference between using the accessor and using the variable directly. KVO and memory management being two big differences.