# Is there 2 methods for declaring instance variables in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In most tutorials, the way to declare instance variable is to put it in .h

```
@interface myViewController: UIViewController {

    UITextField *myTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

and in .m

```
@implementation myViewController
@synthetize myTextField;
```

But in this standford University course http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id480479762 the way to do so is rather

In .h do only:

```
@interface myViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

In .m do this:

```
@synthetize myTextField = _myTextField;
```

Are they equivalent ? Is the second method specific to iOS5 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any reason to declare ivars if you're using properties exclusively in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903651/is-there-any-reason-to-declare-ivars-if-youre-using-properties-exclusively-in-o)

Comment: the `@property` and `@synthesize` (and `@dynamic`) keywords were added in the 2.0 version of the language specification.  if you're an apple developer, their [Objective-C Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) reference is useful knowledge

Comment: @Josh my question is not about if I should use ivars or not: I want to  use them. My question is about 2 ways of declaring them. Or maybe I don't know what ivars is because I'm newbie but I'm talking of instance variables in the same as other programming languages.

Comment: Your first snippet declares the ivar explicitly (between the curly braces in the `@interface` block); the second creates it via `@synthesize`. The question I linked may not be an exact exact duplicate, but the answer to your question is there, and there are a number of other questions linked from it that also cover this.

Comment: If it isn't an exact duplicate then it is worth asking and for other newbies to read it. But thanks for the link I'll read it seems interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent. In ObjC 2.0 the `synthesize` keyword will automatically create the associated ivar if you do not specify one as part of the `synthesize` statement. This functionality is present on all modern runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

They both work the same way, in the last one you actually have an instance variable named _myTextField. I don't know when this "feature" started, and would be interesting to know if the variable is inserted by the compiler or pre-compiler...

Answer (score 1):

diffrence exist, in first variant you can see value of param in debugger
in second variant you can't see value of param in debug mode

Comment: OK I'll check tomorrow if true I'll give you the right answer ;)