# How to do lazy instantiation in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

In one of the [Standford IOS tutorials](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id480479762), the instructor uses lazy instantiation for creating an instance of calculator engine class.

He uses the second syntax exposed in [my former question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9539997/41688):

```
@synthesize myTextField = _myTextField;
```

In this syntax the getter `myTextField` has different name from `_myTextField` so it is possible to test

```
if (_myTextField != nil) { ... }
```

How do I do this with classical first syntax, since the getter and instance variable name are the same (`myTextField`)?

Answer (score 4):

if you use `@sythensize variableName = _variableName;` then the instance variable will be called `_variableName` and that is what you need to use to access it directly. `variableName` is the name which will be used to generate setters and getters, so `self.variableName or [self setVariableName:...]`

if you use `@synthesize variableName;` then the instance variable will have the same name as the synthesised setters and getters. You can still access the instance variable with `variableName = ...` but its easier to get mixed up which one you should be using

so 2 lazy loading implemetations

```
@synthesize varName = _varName

- (id)varName
{
    if (!_varName)
        _varName = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    return _varName;
}
```

or

```
@synthesize varName;

- (id)varName
{
    if (!varName)
        varName = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    return varName;
}
```

Personally, I go for `@synthesize varName = _varName` its much easier to read and harder to mix up when you're accessing the variable when you meant the setter and vice versa

Comment: Or just use ARC and forget about which you are setting :)

Comment: Even with ARC, you don't want to bypass the accessor unintentionally. That breaks KVO and any other side effects that might be in the accessor. Side effects like this lazy instantiation that you'd quietly miss if you used `varName` rather than `self.varName`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII yeah using arc eliminates a lot of the memory headaches, but I've generally stuck with the convention so you know which you are accessing. Also using ARC wouldn't change the lazy loading implementation, the above would work for ARC and memory managed apps (assuming varName was retained)